# Finding A Book Of Black And White Nature / Landscape Photos By An American Photographer Working In the Early to Mid 20th Century

Tags: landscape, photographer

I'm hoping someone can suggest 1) the name of the photographer, and 2) the name of the book. I'm afraid my description is pretty vague as I saw the book a long time ago and memory is a slippery thing.

Things I'm pretty sure about:

1. The book contained only black and white photos
2. The majority were taken in a forest, showing trees, glades, rocky banks etc. Beautifully (naturally) Lit. They weren't grand landscapes in the style of Ansel Adams's better known work, but much smaller scale - intimate, beautifully composed vignettes.
3. There were some photos taken of a log cabin or wooden building.
4. The photographer was American and the photos were taken in America.

Things I'm uncertain about (these might be red herrings):

1. The photos were from a plate camera
2. The photos were pre-1940, possibly 20s or before.

Things I'm by no means certain of:

1. The photographers wife and daughter appeared in some photos (no it wasn't Callahan).
2. Although the book contained pictures from a particular place, I have the impression it wasn't just one of many books of photos of his, but that this was the entirity of his work and that he was perhaps a gifted amateur.

I knew very little of photography / photographers back then, so it could be someone really well known who I haven't encountered since (but I now have a reasonable knowledge of photographers albeit with some pretty sizeable holes in) and I remember it putting me in the mind of Theroux/Walden, but I'm pretty sure it wasn't Weston (looked at a lot of his books and it wan't among them) and definitely wasn't either of the Adamses.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you describe the specifics in the title of this question

Answer (score 2):

It was Wynn Bullock and I think this was the book:

[image]

Here are a few of the images I remembered:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for coming back with the answer.  Could you please put more unique description in the title of the question, so that it might help someone else — and not disappoint people looking for a different book / photographer?

Comment: Done. Feel free to improve.